# Remove code lines from android project on release build

Tags: java, logging, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a Logger class in which I put a string and log Level.
the line looks like this:

```
  Logger.log("The error is" + err , Logger.DEBUG);
```

I would like to remove all Logger.log messages that are using Logger.DEBUG log level on release build.
Currently I haven't found a trick to do this using gradle.
Also i tried using proguard -assumenosideeffects but I can't find the exact rule to submit it for all the project. Proguard says:

> You can let ProGuard remove logging code. The trick is to specify that
>   the logging methods don't have side-effects — even though they
>   actually do, since they write to the console or to a log file.
>   ProGuard will take your word for it and remove the invocations (in the
>   optimization step) and if possible the logging classes and methods
>   themselves (in the shrinking step).

Comment: Do you really need to remove those lines or do you just want to be sure that they are not executed? There are 3rd party libs like `slf4j` which "ignore" your log statements (means they are not creating your log strings) if the log level is not set to ERROR, FATAL etc.

Comment: I want to remove it because event if I'll not execute the command a String append in the function will occur.

Comment: if it's not too much time consuming I'd switch it to `slf4j`. They let you use parametrized messages for logging which avoid string append if the log level is not given.This way you can use `logger.debug("The error is {}", err)`. The string concat will only be done if the level is `debug`. If you can`t switch then sorry, if this was off topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a gradle script:

```
task deleteJavaDebugLogs << {
    description "This function will delete all SDK DEBUG log level from the project, be careful with it!"
    FileTree  javaFiles = fileTree('src/main/java/com/"your-name"') {
        include '**/*.java'
    }
    String regex = "Logger.log[^,]+[^L]+(.*)Logger.SDK_DEBUG[^;];"
    javaFiles.each { File javaFile ->
        println "Start replacing regex on $javaFile.name"
        String content = javaFile.getText()
        content = content.replaceAll(regex, "")
        javaFile.setText(content)
    }
}
```

Every time before release I run this gradle script.
With Regex It's removing only the problematic lines from the project.
**I suggest adding that to your build procedure with Jenkins or other build tool**.

Be careful running that on a none backed-up project because it will remove all lines from your code with the above regex.